# Custom POS Sales Order Import Scenario

Tags: acumatica

I had this error while importing in Sales Order, I tried to ask the partner here of acumatica but they don't know the cause or solution, do you have any idea why this thing occur? pls refer to the screenshot. thanks.

**Problem:**

> Error: An error occurred during processing of the field InventoryID:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that all the items/customers are present in the System where you are importing records?

Comment: Yes sir, because if I re-run the import it goes ok, I just don't know why it appears randomly.

Comment: Random issues tend to be difficult to investigate. Quite often those issues are not totally random. For example it could always fail on first try after executing IISReset/Restart Application but succeed on second call. When that's the case its a strong signal that the issue is related to loading cache in memory. On first run it does the process before inserting the cache. Process fails but object is now in cache so second run works fine. By restarting the application that flushes the cache and the issue can be reproduced which greatly helps investigation. Just noticed this is an old question..